# Using Randoop To Generate Test Cases (Based on Pre- and Post- Conditions)

Tags: junit, randoop, random-testing

I am trying to use Randoop (by following [Randoop Manual](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#spec-json-method-specifications)) to generate test cases based on pre- and post- conditions specification stored in a JSON file.

Target program is the following (buggy) Java method.

```java
package com.example.math;

public class Math {
    /*Expected Behavior:
          Given upperBound >= 0, the method returns
               1 + 2 + ... + upperBound                 
      But This method is buggy and works only on
      inputs with odd value, e.g. for upperBound == 4,
      the method returns 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 1 instead of
      1 + 2 + 3 + 4                                   */
    public static int sum(int upperBound) {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= upperBound; i++) {
            s += i;
        }
        if (upperBound % 2 == 0) {// <--------- BUG!
            s++;                  // <--------- BUG!
        }                         // <--------- BUG!
        return s;
    }
}
```

And I use the following JSON file to specify the desired behavior of the method:

```
[
  {
    "operation": {
      "classname": "com.example.math.Math",
      "name": "sum",
      "parameterTypes": [ "int" ]
    },
    "identifiers": {
      "parameters": [ "upperBound" ],
      "returnName": "res"
    },
    "post": [
      {
        "property": {
          "condition": "res == upperBound * (upperBound + 1) / 2",
          "description": ""
        },
        "description": "",
        "guard": {
          "condition": "true",
          "description": ""
        }
      }
    ],
    "pre": [
      {
        "description": "upperBound must be non-negative",
        "guard": {
          "condition": "upperBound >= 0",
          "description": "upperBound must be non-negative"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I compile the program, and run the following command to apply Randoop so as to generate test cases based on the correctness specification:

```sh
java -cp my-classpath:$RANDOOP_JAR randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=com.example.math.Math --output-limit=200 --specifications=spec.json
```

Where `spec.json` is the JSON file containing the above specification for method contracts. I have got two questions:

1. Why does not changing `--output-limit` change the number of generated test cases? For sufficiently large numbers, it seems that I always get only 8 regression test cases two of which checking the method `getClass` does not return `null` value (even though that is not part of my specification). Please kindly let me know how I can generate more regression test cases. Am I missing a command-line option?
2. It seems that Randoop does not consult the specification inside `spec.json` when it tries to generate *error-revealing* test cases. Can we make Randoop generate error-revealing test cases on every input that violates the provided post-condition?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Why does not changing `--output-limit` change the number of generated test cases?

Randoop generates tests, then outputs a subset of them.  For example, Randoop does not output subsumed tests, which appear as a subsequence of some longer test.

This is mentioned obliquely in the [documentation for `--output-limit`](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#option:output-limit).

> two of which checking the method `getClass` does not return null value (even though that is not part of my specification)

`getClass()` is a method in `Math` (the class under test), so Randoop calls `getClass()`.  At test generation time, the return value was not null, so Randoop made an assertion to that effect.

There is nothing special about `getClass()`; Randoop would create similar regression tests for other methods.

> 2. It seems that Randoop does not consult the specification inside `spec.json`

There was a bug in Randoop's handling of postcondition specifications for static methods.  The bug has been [fixed](https://github.com/randoop/randoop/commit/caed7805c3d171c94be6a876a53d9d157d1fd9d4).

To report a bug, it is better to use [Randoop's issue tracker](https://github.com/randoop/randoop/issues), as noted in the [Randoop manual](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#bug-reporting).  The options for [getting help](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#getting_help) also include mailing lists.  Unlike Stack Overflow, the issue tracker and mailing list permit discussions and tracking current status.  Thanks!